# Karma-Jasmine: Expected undefined to be defined + Controller + Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run a Unit Test on a Controller, but I am facing the following Error:

```
Expected undefined to be defined.
```

I know what is undefined, but I don't know why it is undefined and how to fix that.
Let me paste my code for better understanding.

**Controller**

```
angular
    .module("app.licensing", [])
    .controller("LicensingController", LicensingController)

    LicensingController.$inject = ["textService"];

    function LicensingController(textService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.licForm = {
            accountName: null,
            ticketNo: null
        };

        vm.controlLabels = textService.licensing.controlLabels;
    }
```

**textService** Text Service basically just contain Object for Strings and returns an Object.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory("textService", textService)

    function textService() {
        return {

            //Object for Licensing Module
            licensing: {
                pageTitle: "Page Title",
                controlLabels: {
                    accountName: "Account Name",
                    ticketNo: "Ticket No",
                    hostId: "Host Id",
                }
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

**Unit Test**

```
describe("-----> LicensingController", function () {

    var LicensingController;
    var textService;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app.licensing"));

    beforeEach(function () {

        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value("textService", textService);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {

        LicensingController = _$controller_("LicensingController", {
        });
    }));

    describe("-----> Licensing Form", function () {

        it("--> License Controller should be Defined.", function () {
            expect(LicensingController).toBeDefined();
        });

        it("--> 'licForm' Object must be Defined.", function () {
            expect(LicensingController.licForm).toBeDefined();
        });

        it("--> 'controlLabels' Object must be Defined.", function () {
            expect(LicensingController.controlLabels).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

- In the Unit Test, the 3rd Test (controlLabels) is firing the error. Here, the controlLabels is undefined. Is it because the value is coming from textService?
- But why it is undefined and how to solve that.
- Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not injecting a mock `textService` into `LicensingController` in your `beforeEach`.  Add that and it should start working.

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _textService_) {    
    LicensingController = _$controller_("LicensingController", { textService: _textService_ });
}));
```

You also need to remove the second `beforeEach` or at least provide a mock implementation of `textService` in there.

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module(function($provide) { 
    $provide.service('textService', function () {
        return {

          //Object for Licensing Module
          licensing: {
            pageTitle: "Page Title",
            controlLabels: {
              accountName: "Account Name",
              ticketNo: "Ticket No",
              hostId: "Host Id",
            }
          }
      };
    });
}));
```

Comment: I tried injecting the Service in various ways. And also tried creating SpyObj. But nothing is working. :(

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer with a better example of injecting the mock service.

Comment: If I paste the code "$provide.service('textService').....", then the Unit Test is working no matter if you inject the textService in Controller or not. 

Honestly speaking, I don't know what is happening, but the Test works.

Just one question: If my "textService" has 200 lines of code, do I need to include all that 200 lines of code in the Unit Test also?

Comment: @AnkitPrajapati, this is up to you - you can test your controller or you can test your controller + your service. If service redirect call to $http - it ius worth to mock it. If service just stores some text constants - there is really no reason to mock it. Just add module with your service to test. beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));